# Sails js -model resultset variable scope

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Can someone explain to me why i can't save the booksCount variable into the users json object? Here's my code

```
for(var user in users){
    Books.count({author: users[user]['id']}).exec(function(err, count){
        users[user]['booksCount']=count;
        });
    }
return res.view('sellers', {data: users});
```

Where Users is the list of users from the table which is the direct result of a User.find() method. User is the model.

Now if i try to print the users[user]['booksCount'] inside the for loop, it works fine. But when it goes outside the for loop the variable vanishes into thin air. Console prints 'undefined' outside for loop.

Comment: Because you do it async. Why don't you just populate books of user when you fetch all users?

Comment: This is what i did, 1) fetch all authors list from books 2) Populate the array of users 3) Find count of books for each of them. There is no Author table. A user can be an Author too. That's why i did it this way.

Comment: Thanks, let me see what i can do in here

Comment: Can you show your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Books.count is an API call and all the API call are async so In

```
for(var user in users){
    // It Will call the Books.count and leave the callback Function without waiting for callback response.
    Books.count({author: users[user]['id']}).exec(function(err, count){ 
       users[user]['booksCount']=count;
    });
}
//As callback result didn't came here but the controll came here
// So, users[user] will be undefined here
return res.view('sellers', {data: users});
```

Use promises:

```
async.forEachOf(users, function (value, user, callback) {
    Books.count({author: users[user]['id']}).exec(function(err, count){ 
           users[user]['booksCount']=count;
           callback(err);
         // callback function execute after getting the API result only
        });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err.message); // Or Error view
    // You will find the data into the users[user]
    return res.view('sellers', {data: users});
});
```